Fastest PDF Viewer SDK for C#
I have an old application that displays a PDF and allows me to zoom to x15 and scroll around to a specific point determined by a mouse click when the PDF is shrunk to fit the screen.
The PDF is typically 1200mmx900mm in size and I click 2-3 points then require the PDF to zoom to a predetermined size (x15) and then scroll so the centre of the display is the mouse click position.
For the old application we used Adobe Acrobat SDK and built on their StativView example in C++. We took screen dumps of a region pf interest and output .BMP files along with the position relative to the bottom left corner of the PDF.
This was then input into a second program written in C that controlled an XY table fitted with a camera.
We now need to convert both programs into one application in C#.
We need a fast,simple and inexpensive SDK that can be easily integrated.
Performance is crucial we need to load the PDF as quickly as possible and be able to zoom and scroll in less than 1 second.
We don't need any other features.
Any recommendations would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance,
Des

We recommend using Syncfusion's WPF PdfViewer control for scrolling and zooming to higher percentages in the WPF applications.
By default, maximum zoom percentage of Pdfviewer is 400, but we can change to desired percentage. To zoom above 400, we must set the MaximumZoomPercentage API value when initializing the control and can zoom to your desired percentage using the ZoomTo API. For more information, please refer to the following User Guide link:
UG link:
https://help.syncfusion.com/wpf/pdf-viewer/viewing-pdf-files#open-pdf-file-from-the-local-disk-using-toolbar
https://help.syncfusion.com/wpf/pdf-viewer/magnifying-pdf-documents#define-the-minimum-and-maximum-zoom-percentage
In terms of scrolling, the PdfViewer control allows for faster scrolling of pages even at high zoom percentages. We have implemented virtualization to render the pdf pages at higher zoom levels, resulting in improved performance.
For further details and live working examples in your required platform, please contact Syncfusion support(mailto : support@syncfusion.com).
